# How to model 1:N:M in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a requirement to create a schema of a school in dynamodb. The requirement is as follows :

1. Each school contains a list of course group. [1:N]
2. Each course group contains a list of courses. [1:N]
3. Each course contains a list of modules [1:N]

Each entity has a corresponding set of attributes. Here is my first take on the schema

School - School Id - Hash Key, Attributes.
Course Group : School Id - Hashkey, course Group - Range Key with attributes
Courses : School Id - HashKey, [courseGroup + CourseName] - Range Key with attributes.
Modules : School Id - HashKey, [CourseGroup + CourseName + ModuleName] - Range Key with Attributes.

The problem with the above schema is that if I want to create a module upfront with creating a course and CourseGroup it does not work. Also I have the following queries that I wish to perform on this schema.

1. Get the list of all the course groups and courses and modules for a given school.
2. Get the list of Course Groups for a given school.
3. Get the list of courses for a given course group.
4. Get the list of all modules for a given course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the initial schema that I have come up with:

```
school (schoolId(hash), otherAttributes)
courseGroup (gpId(hash), schoolId(range), array of courseIds , othersAttributes)
     courseGroupIndex(schoolId(hash), otherAttribute) -- Global Secondary Index
courses (courseId, array of moduleIds, othersAttributes)
modules (moduleId , othersAttributes)
```

The most important thing to note over here is that actually there is no link between two tables even if the name of the columns are same, You need to join these tables at application level

Let see if all your queries are covered:

1. Get the list of all the course groups and courses and modules for a
   given school.

   **Pass schoolId in courseGroup table get all courseIds -> pass courseIds in courses table to get all moduleIds -> pass moduleId to get all modules from module table**
2. Get the list of Course Groups for a given school.

   **Pass schoolId in courseGroupIndex table to get all courcesGroup**
3. Get the list of courses for a given course group.

   **Pass courseGroupId in courseGroup table to get all courseIds**
4. Get the list of all modules for a given course.

   **Pass courseId in course table to get all moduleIds**

Hope That helps